# Asio certificate verify failed

Tags: c++, ssl, ssl-certificate, boost-asio

I downloaded Asio Standalone and would like to run the ssl example (client and server) provided with the Asio source code on my local computer. I managed to get the library running. The code compiles without errors. But I think the  client has a problem reading the server certificate from the certificate store on my debian system in /etc/ssl/certs. Because I get the following error:

> Handshake failed: certificate verify failed

What I did so far:

1. I created the server certificate and key as descripted in [my last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135949/boost-asio-certificate-and-key-not-found) and added the crt file to /etc/ssl/certs
2. I set the verify_path on client side as following:

> ```
> asio::ssl::context ctx(asio::ssl::context::tlsv11);
> ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
> ```

3. I start the server on port 8877 on my local computer
4. I start the client with host IP 127.0.0.1 and port 8877

then I get the error as mentioned above.

Am I right that asio finds my certificate? (because otherwise I would expect an error 'file_not_found' or something like that) Why is the certificate not valid? Because I self-signed it or because I don't use 127.0.0.1 as a 'Common Name' in the certificate ? But I guess the client should accept a self-signed certificate in it's local certificate store...